# Unable to grep foreign language in shell script

Tags: shell-script, grep, pcregrep

I am a newbie in shell scripting, I have a text which contain text in following format:-

```
"some foreign language",'corresponding ID to text'
```

for example:-

```
"Назад",IDC_SSB_DLG_BACK_BTN
```

I need to find the text related to ID and save in in text file.

Here my sample script:-

```
#!/bin/sh
target_file=$1
output=$2
translationID=IDC_SSB_DLG_BACK_BTN
translation=$(cat $target_file | grep $translationID)
translationValue=$(echo "$translation" | awk -F',' '{print $1}')
translationValueFinal=$(echo "$translationValue" | tr -d '"')
echo "$translationValueFinal" >> $output
```

while running this script I am getting error :-`grep: (standard input): binary file matches`

Please suggest a way to grep and save a foriegn language in shell script. Thanks

Comment: @choroba sorry typing error was there. Fixed it now. thanks

Comment: What encoding does the input file use? When using UTF-8, I'm getting `Назад` as the output.

Comment: Not sure about encoding part. How I can check it?

Comment: Run the line through a hex dump. e.g. `grep IDC_SSB_DLG_BACK_BTN file | xxd`. What output do you get? Also, what tool do you use to check the output? Make sure it uses the correct encoding, too.

Comment: You can also specify `grep -a` to force the text interpretation of the input.

Comment: I am using notepad++ on windows. Actually I am using ubuntu on VM. SO, I am running script on ubuntu & checking output on windows notepad++

Comment: using grep -a did work for me. Thanks for your help

Comment: This means your file is malformed, it contains NUL (`\0`) bytes. You probably want to fix the process that generates the file.

Comment: What is the `target_file` exactly? It seems you are trying to use grep on a GNU Gettext .mo file or a similar binary format. If so, use the tools appropriate for the job. grep is meant for "text files" (as per POSIX definition).

Comment: Its a simple txt file

Comment: As @terdon mentioned above, a text file cannot have NUL bytes in it. This is how grep detects "binary files" as opposed to "text files" (`binary file matches`) - by the presence of stray NULs.

Comment: Related: [Text File](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) in POSIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the GNU grep, you can tell grep to treat the input as text no matter what characters it encounters.

```
grep -a
```

But it seems there are some non-textual bytes in the input, so better check the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `grep` and a bunch of extra code for this as you want to do a literal string match on a specific field, which grep cannot do on it's own, and the tools that can do it don't require help from other tools.

Your existing command:

```
translationID=IDC_SSB_DLG_BACK_BTN
grep $translationID
```

even if we added the [missing `"`s](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) to make it `grep "$translationID"` would fail if any of these conditions were true:

1. The string in the first field matched the id, e.g. `IDC_SSB_DLG_BACK_BTN,any`, or
2. The string in either field contained a different string which that ID was a substring of, e.g. `any,FOOIDC_SSB_DLG_BACK_BTNBAR` or `FOOIDC_SSB_DLG_BACK_BTNBAR,any`.
3. The string in the second field and the ID variable contained a regexp metachar, e.g. `any,foo.bar` and `any,foodbar` would both match `translationID=foo.bar`.

and probably others. See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more info on some of these types of issue.

Using this input file, for example:

```
$ cat file
any1,foodbar
foo.bar,any2
foofoo.barbar,any3
any4,foofoo.barbar
"Назад",foo.bar
```

where we want to print the value from the first field when the second field is the string `foo.bar` (i.e. just the last line above):

```
$ translationID=foo.bar
```

here's your `grep` command finding the expected line but also making many false matches and so outputting undesirable lines:

```
$ grep "$translationID" file
any1,foodbar
foo.bar,any2
foofoo.barbar,any3
any4,foofoo.barbar
"Назад",foo.bar
```

vs this `awk` command only matching the correct line (as well as outputting just the desired field):

```
$ awk -F',' -v id="$translationID" '$2==id{print $1}' file
"Назад"
```

or if you want the quotes removed there are lots of options including:

```
$ awk -F'[,"]+' -v id="$translationID" '$3==id{print $2}' file
Назад
```

That awk command is doing a full-field literal* string comparison of just the target field so it will be accurate whereas your grep command is doing a partial-line regexp comparison which will fail some time unless you're lucky with your input values.

*slight caveat - if `translationID` contains backslashes that you want treated literally then you need to do:

```
$ id="$translationID" awk -F',' '$2==ENVIRON["id"]{print $1}' file
"Назад"
```

or similar instead, see [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script).

If your input file can contain NUL chars then use GNU awk or some other awk that documents they support that since awk is a text processing tool and so is only required to work with text files as input and per the POSIX definition a text file cannot contain UL chars, and with GNU awk you MAY need to set [BINMODE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#User_002dmodified), e.g.:

```
awk -v BINMODE=3 -F',' -v id="$translationID" '$2==id{print $1}' file
```